# $f(x) = (x + 1)(x − 2)^2$ . a Sketch the curve $y = f(x)$, showing the coordinates of any points where the curve meets the coordinate axes.

Tags: derivatives

I tried putting $y=0$, then having $(x+1)$, $(x-2)$, $(x-2)$; where $x$ would equal $(0,..)$ respectively. Is that correct, and not sure what to sketch?

Comment: 2.a bit before 'Sketch' needs editing out.

Comment: The abscissa(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa) $=0$ for $y$ axis

Comment: Is $f=(x+1)(x-2)^2$ the function you want to study?

Comment: yes that is the function

Answer (score 0):

Hope this graph helps -

its of $f(x)=(x+1)(x-2)^2$
[image]

\\\\\\\\\\\\\**EDIT**\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
Here you can substitute for $y=f(x)$ and then take different values of $x$
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
x & \text{y}  \\
\hline
-1 & (-1+1)(-1-2)^2=\color{blue}{0}  \\
1 & (1+1)(1-2)^2=\color{blue}{2}  \\
2 & (2+1)(2-1)^2=\color{blue}{0}  \\
3 & (3+1)(3-1)^2=\color{blue}{4}    \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: How did you get from the function to the graph?

Comment: @user108815 I have edited my answer to make it as requested